# Ghost-capturing robot won't capture ghosts

Tags: two-point-hospital

In Two-Point Hospital (PC, Close Encounters DLC), I have all of the robot janitors roaming around my hospital. They're all functioning well, except for the one with the Ghost Capturing skill. This robot simply refuses to capture ghosts. Basically he does nothing but repair machinery.

[image: Janitor stats]
[image: Janitor skillz]

As you can see, "Sprinkle Spectre" has the ghost capture skill, but according to his stats he's managed to capture exactly 0 ghosts in the nearly-23 years I've employed him.

Is this a known issue? Is there a way to fix it?

The only mention of this I found was on the [Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/535930/discussions/0/2626095078197815940/) but the question was derailed talking about a completely separate game, but it sounded like that person had a similar issue.

Comment: Is he assigned to ghost capture in the [job assignment list](https://two-point-hospital.fandom.com/wiki/Staff#Job_Assignment)?

Comment: Yes. That is literally the only thing he can do other than fix things and water plants. But even when I try to drop him near a ghost, there is no "Capture a ghost" action that ever shows.